# Identify when stop modifying a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event where it makes change practically every second the value of a tag and from time to time that value stops at once.

```
<div class="tiempo" time="10"></div>
```

What I want to do is to listen to the div/tag through another event and let them know if the previous event has stopped or is still running.

In other words, what I want is to show me an alert when that value stops changing.

I hope you understand me because my english is not good :D

Thank you very much.

Comment: How exactly does the value change?

Comment: Is a library that manipulates the iframes http://playerjs.io  player.on('timeupdate', function(data){

 $duration.attr("time", data.duration.toFixed(1));
    
    });

Comment: Please check out clearTimeout() example https://www.elated.com/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Answer (score 0):

How about using set interval and wrapping the alert in a function using service worker?

Comment: I find the setInterval inefficient but how exactly would you do it? 

With an example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `setTimeout` function that compares the values over a range of time then you do something with the result when the value remains the same, you should also remember to call `clearTimeout` after your values stop changing. cheers!

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work because the value you get is always the same.

Could you give me an example please?